# Find a finite set $S$ that a point in $S$ can be represented as convex combination of $n+1$ points in $S$

Tags: convex-optimization

What kind of finite set that belongs to $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $P$ points $(P\geq n+1)$ satisfy both of the following conditions:

1. There exist a set of $n+1$ points in $S$ such that every point in $\operatorname{Conv}(S)$ can be represented as a convex combination of these $n+1$ points.
2. There does not exist any $k < n+1$ points such that every point in $\operatorname{Conv}(S)$ can be represented as a convex combination of these $n+1$ points.

Does this question ask me to find a specific finite set or just one with some restrictions?

From Caratheodory's theorem, given a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for every point $x$ in $\operatorname{Conv}(S)$ there exists a convex combination of no more than $n+1$ points from $S$ . I think this theorem guarantees that a finite set with cardinality more than $n+1$ can satisfy these two conditions. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you considered the case $n=2$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. For future posts , please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: It means that $S$  is the convex hull of $n+1$ affinely independent points. In particular, it is a $n$ dimensional simplex.

Comment: I check the content about simplex, I think you are right!  When n=2, a triangle will meet these conditions, so does general n.